# Using a tab as a hyperlink button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I'm working on a asp.net project and I want my tabs to work as a hyperlink. When the user clicks on the the tab, it gets selected and the user is redirected to another URL.

This is how my code looks right now.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab">För elever</a></li>
  <li><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab">För skolpersonal</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab">Ungdom och elevdatabas</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="aaa">lalalla</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">För skolpersonal</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">Ungdom och elevdatabas</div>
</div>
```

Should I do this using jQuery? I just want the user to get redirected when the tab is clicked.

Comment: If it's working without Jquery then why use it?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal The tabs are working without jQuery but how do I make the tabs hyperlink?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. The point of a tab UI is that it changes the displayed content, not that it goes to a different page. If it does to a different page then the tabs will go away. If the tabs are going away instead of switching between them, why have them in the first place?

Comment: `<li><a href="https://www.google.co.in/" data-toggle="tab">Go to google</a></li>` add one LI

Comment: @Quentin Yeah I realized it didn't make sense. I replaced the tabs with normal buttons instead. How can I redirect using normal buttons?

Comment: just add a link to the page you want it to go to, replace `#aaa` with `hhtp://www.link.org/page_to_go_to.asp` or something

Comment: @John — Normal buttons are things to dangle JavaScript from. If you want to redirect somewhere, use a link. You an apply CSS to make it look the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `active` class on that button or tab with condition like if its home page then it will add `active` class to Home button.